# Are there currently any plans to replace Rhythmbox with Banshee in "Maverick Meerkat" 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, rhythmbox, banshee

Since years there are rumours that Rhythmbox will be replaced by Banshee as default application in the next Distribution-Release. Are there any plans for it to be replaced? The information that I have found is ambiguous.

Comment: That's a very subjective and argumentative question, since there is now way to be sure, right now.

Comment: Changed the question to be less argumentative

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This hasn't been finalized yet. You can see on their whiteboard though that it's on the table for discussion: [Ubuntu Blueprints: Desktop Application Selection for Maverick](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-maverick-desktop-application-selection) It comes down to several issues not only with the quality of the application, but it's size (for LiveCD), dependencies, and upstream's development cycle.

This shows a running log of discussions and inputs. As is noted at the bottom Banshee has some issues in the Upstream which might prevent it from making it's way into 10.10.

Comment: I think ultimately it's unlikely this release.

Comment: Although interesting one of the 'upstream issues', has just been fixed. (http://www.lamalex.net/2010/08/omg-thats-so-2009/)

Answer (score 2):

Banshee will become the default music player in 11.04 (Natty Narwhal).  See also the whiteboard at https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-desktop-n-application-selection (please don't edit!).

Answer (score 1):

I think that will be decided during the upcoming Ubuntu Developer Summit in Florida.

Comment: No, the next UDS will be after 10.10 is released. It will likely get discussed in reference to 11.04 though.

Answer (score 1):

Banshee has replaced Rhythmbox on UNE 10.10 Alpha 3

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to have an answer on the Desktop-Edition!